# Ripple Emulator Proxy Error

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, ripple

I am using ripple emulator to run/debug my cordova mobile application. I am making a call to weblogic server using jquery ajax. It works fine with http url. When i change the URL to https i get the below error in ripple emulator.

```
ERROR: Proxying failed with: { [Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same problem currently.

Comment: I am testing with http only on the dev environment but i just tried hitting our test environment with https and it worked. did you try by setting Cross Domain Proxy = local?

Comment: Yeah I have set Cross Domain Proxy to local. Not sure if I'm getting this due to the fact that I'm using a self-signed certificate though.

Comment: I tried hitting my localhost with https and got the same error. May be related to selfsigned certificate.

Comment: Ok that explains it then. Thanks Baskar. Its a bit of a schlep though.